# jquery Datatables IE7 and IE8 diplay issue: table gets highlighted in blue when user attempts to move a column

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatables

Maybe someone has encountered this Datatables problem before ?

I have a jquery Datatables that works fine in Firefox & Chrome. When the exact same table is displayed in IE7 and IE8 it does not display correctly. Firefox and Chrome are the most up to date versions.

The problem manifests itself as follows:
- Initial rendering of the Table is fine in all 3 browsers.
- However in IE7 and IE8 as the user selects a column and attempts to move it the whole table from that column forward gets high lighted in blue as well as the rest of the screen.

Here is my table definition:

```
oTable = 
$('#datalog').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',                        // Specify exactly where in the DOM you want DataTables to inject the various controls: http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom
    "oColReorder": {
        "aiOrder": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],    // Defaults for setting the Columns. See "aoColumns" entries.
        "iFixedColumns": 2                              // Prevent first 2 columns in "aoColumns" entries from being moved.
    },
    "oColVis": {
        "aiExclude": [ 0, 1 ],                          // Prevent the columns in "aoColumns" from being enabled/disabled.
        "buttonText": $("#ressShowHideColumns").text()  // Localise Column Show/Hide button.
    },
    "bFilter": false,                       // Disable the Search Text box i.e. disable filtering
    "bSort": false,                         // Disable sorting of Columns
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "bStateSave": true,                     // Save State e.g. Column order, which columns are hidden, pagination.
    "sScrollY": "365px",                    // Allow a vertical scroll bar. Make the table xxxpx high
    "bPaginate": true,                      // Enable Pagination.
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",      // Use full set of Pagination Navigation buttons. Default is two (Previous & Next).
    "bInfo": true,                          // Enable display table info: "Showing X to XXX of XXX entries" 
    "bAutoWidth": true,                     // Auto width for display of Columns
    "bProcessing": true,                    // Display "Processing" when page is busy
    "bServerSide": true,                    // Get the data from the Server
    "sAjaxSource": ajaxURL,     // URL used to update Table via Ajax calls.
    "bJQueryUI": true,                      // Use JQuery UI Theme instead of the default Datatables theme
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "col0" },            // 0 - Column Array Index Position
        { "mDataProp": "col1" },        // 1
        { "mDataProp": "col2" },    // 2
        { "mDataProp": "col3" },    // 3
        { "mDataProp": "col4" },    // 4
        { "mDataProp": "col5" },    // 5 
        { "mDataProp": "col6" },    // 6
        { "mDataProp": "col7" },    // 7
        { "mDataProp": "col8" },    // 8 
        { "mDataProp": "col9" }     // 9 - Column Array Index Position
    ],
    "oLanguage": {                          // Internationalisation: http://datatables.net/ref#oLanguage
        "sLengthMenu": $("#ressLengthMenu").text(),
        "sZeroRecords": $("#ressZeroRecords").text(),
        "sInfo": $("#ressInfo").text(),
        "sInfoEmpty": $("#ressInfoEmpty").text(),
        "sEmptyTable": $("#ressEmptyTable").text(),
        "sLoadingRecords": $("#ressLoadingRecords").text(),
        "sProcessing": $("#ressProcessing").text(),
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": $("#ressFirst").text(),
            "sLast": $("#ressLast").text(),
            "sNext": $("#ressNext").text(),
            "sPrevious": $("#ressPrevious").text()
        }
     },
     "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
         $.ajax( {
           "dataType": 'json',
           "type": "POST",
           "url": sSource,
           "data": aoData,
           "success": fnCallback
         } );
     }
});
```

Any information appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the **bAutoWidth** option to false.